# how to get one line of data form a standard input C

Tags: c

I want to gets one line of data from standard input. Returns an empty string at end of the file. If the data line will not fit in the allotted space, stores the portion that does fit and discards the rest of the input line.

I could write this one but I keep getting this error what does it mean?

`subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector dest[i++] = ch;`

```
char *
scanline(char dest,    /* output   - destination string        */
         int  dest_len) /* input    - space available in dest   */
{
    int i, ch;

    /* Gets next line one character at a time.                */
    i = 0;
    for (ch = getchar();
         ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i < dest_len - 1;
         ch = getchar())
        dest[i++] = ch;
    dest[i] = '\0';

    /* Discards any characters that remain on input line        */
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        ch = getchar();

    return (dest);
}
```

Comment: Why not `fgets`?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And please fix indentation.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description. And please provide a [mre]. Your problem can be in another part of the code you're not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C lets you use the subscript operator `[]` on arrays and on pointers. In your code, the variable `dest` is neither an array nor a pointer.

A possible solution could be to replace

```
char *scanline(char dest, int dest_len) {
```

with

```
char *scanline(char *dest, int dest_len) {
```

or

```
char *scanline(char dest[], int dest_len) {
```

Also, when you call the `scanline()` function, you have to pass a pointer to an array and its size.

Comment: oh, when I read about scanline() but I wasn't passing a pointer. Thanks